# Form Recognizer API Analyze Layout Results in Error InvalidImageURL "Image URL is badly formatted."

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Tried both pdf & png both have the same error.  Verified can view the source file in a browser ie. anonymous access.  Trying to call the method from the API browser at https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-preview/operations/AnalyzeLayoutAsync/console

[image]

Comment: having exactly the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

This "InvalidImageURL" error code can be misleading. It can mean the image is not accessible. Another option to call API is to use binary data, which uses Content-Type: *application/pdf*, *image/jpeg*, *image/png*, or *image/tiff*, instead of using Content-Type: *application/json*, which use image URL.

See my post [here](https://ittichaicham.com/2020/03/call-azure-form-recognizer-api-on-sharepoint-document-image-url-in-power-automate/) if it may help with clarification.

IC

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by serializing the object in the body payload. In python...

```
body = { "source": "https://...." }  
resp = post(url = post_url, data = json.dumps(body), headers = headers, params = params)
```